# Why ActiveAdmin files appearing in Rails logs, each requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, logging

I can't find the origin of the problem.

I'm using Rails 3.1.1 and ActiveAdmin 0.4.0. Web server is WEBrick 1.3.1.

Each request, ActiveAdmin files are shown in the logs. For example:

```
Started GET "/admin/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-17 21:28:37 +0200
[nil, ["path/to/the/app/admin", "path/to/the/app/admin/modela.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelb.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelc.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeld.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modele.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelf.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelg.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelh.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeli.rb"]]
  Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms
```

The app/admin/dashboards.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.build do
end
```

No matter the page, the ActiveAdmin files are shown in the logs...
No matter the environment (development, staging, production, ...)

Another page, another example:

```
[...]

Started GET "/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 12:37:40 +0200
[nil, ["path/to/the/app/admin", "path/to/the/app/admin/modela.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelb.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelc.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeld.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modele.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelf.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelg.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelh.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeli.rb"]]
Served asset /jquery-1.7.1.min.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 12:37:40 +0200
[nil, ["path/to/the/app/admin", "path/to/the/app/admin/modela.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelb.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelc.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeld.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modele.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelf.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelg.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelh.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeli.rb"]]
Served asset /jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 12:37:40 +0200
[nil, ["path/to/the/app/admin", "path/to/the/app/admin/modela.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelb.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelc.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeld.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modele.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelf.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelg.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelh.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeli.rb"]]
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

[...]
```

See, in each request there's:

```
[nil, ["path/to/the/app/admin", "path/to/the/app/admin/modela.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelb.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelc.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeld.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modele.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelf.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelg.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modelh.rb", "path/to/the/app/admin/modeli.rb"]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a "debug line" from the AA team. See: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/952

It was removed by sferik in this commit: 
https://github.com/sferik/active_admin/commit/8bec274d4d0f3d5592c27c18ab8332b555ff8102

Answer (score 0):

Looks like debugging may be turned on somewhere in the stack.

Without performing further blind debugging, can you provide more information about this issue - e.g.:

- What version of Rails you have installed
- What version of ActiveAdmin you have installed
- The Admin::DashboardController code

Comment: Hi, thank for answering. I've edited my post. This problem as shown recently and I can't find what changed in my config/app that produce this...